# Rename [dotnetnuke] to [dnn]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There are about 2000 [dotnetnuke](/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke) questions on Stack Overflow, with [dnn](/questions/tagged/dnn) as a synonym that points back to it. Last July, DotNetNuke formally renamed itself to DNN and renamed the professional edition to Evoq.

Because of this, we should switch the tags, so that [dnn](/questions/tagged/dnn) is the real tag and [dotnetnuke](/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke) is the synonym, and add an [evoq](/questions/tagged/evoq) tag that also points to [dnn](/questions/tagged/dnn).

Comment: How long ago did the name change occur?

Comment: It was in July of '13

Comment: How did that meeting go? "You know what this company is lacking? More ambiguity."